# How to iterate over list of elements after it is staled because webpage is refreshed

Tags: python, html, selenium

Hi I try to iterate over elements, which is a button, that refers to a new page. After obtaining the relevant information within in the new page, I want to go back to the list of buttons (sometimes 2 pages back) and click on the next button. So think in a way of a graph tree, where I need to access every node.

So this is my structure:

```
url = 'www.firstpage.com'
driver.get(url)

Organizations = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_any_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//button")))
for org in Organizations:
    org.click()
    Documents = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_any_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//button")))
    for document in Documents:
        document.click()
  
        
        ##Do some stuff
        ......
        ##After finishing the requested operations, go back to the first page.
        driver.get(url)
        time.sleep(10) #To prevent a possible racing condition
        org.click()
        time.sleep(10) #To prevent a possible racing condition
```

When I do this, I get

```
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: The element reference of 
<button id="1343" class="switcher__organization border border--radius-3 margin--bottom-5"> is 
stale; either the element is no longer attached to the DOM, it is not in the current frame 
context, or the document has been refreshed
```

It has probabily to do with refreshing the page, but I dont know how to solve this. The first loop works, but the moment I want to go to the second document, it gives the error.

I tried `driver.back()`, but that definitely wont work since the structure of some pages (organizations) can differ (sometimes I need 2 times `driver.back()` ).

I tried to store the `href` links, but those are not given in the elements. So that didn't work either.

Can someone help me to solve this.

Comment: Can you confirm the url of the page you're trying to interact with?

Comment: It just an example url. The environment where I actually work in with, is a closed login environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basics of page clicking and using driver.back()

Say I have an element I need to loop which goes to another page from page click. I normally get the count of all elements and then just use the index.
You can also (//button)[i] as an XPATH for a single element.

```
elems=driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//button")
for i in range(len(elems)):
    driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//button")[i].click()
    elems2=driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//button")
    for j in range(len(elems2)):
        driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//button")[j].click()
        # To go back 1 page.
        driver.back()
```

Comment: driver.back() is not usable in every situation, because sometimes I need to do 2 or 3 times driver.back(). Since I want to automize the process, I cann't keep track of that. But keeping track of which i-th element I'm looping over will do. Thanks for the idea.